# Bash History Not Preserved Between Terminal Sessions on Mac

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal, history

My bash history mysteriously stopped working, and I have no idea how to fix it. This is what my .bashrc looks like:

```
HISTSIZE=500
HISTFILESIZE=500
HISTFILE=$HOME/.bash_history
```

However, when i run `echo $HISTFILE` it prints out `/Users/myusername/.bash_sessions/EE8689E5-7DAD-4018-817E-0AF1DE36082A.historynew`.

I am the owner of the .bash_history file, so I'm not too sure how I would go about fixing this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Nelson, welcome to Super User. Quick check- ere those spaces inserted by you?

Comment: yes they were, i'll remove them and report back.

Comment: @bertieb, I've removed the spaces and now $HISTFILESIZE is properly echo'd. However, history remains unsaved and $HISTFILE prints out that odd temp history file (which I'm assuming stores history for just that session).

Comment: Are you trying to change `$HISTFILE`, out of interest? I don't have a `.bashrc` on OSX and `echo $HISTFILE` reports the place I would expect- does commenting out the lines in question have any effect?

Comment: Where are you sourcing `.bashrc`? On OS X, you normally have a login shell.

Comment: @bertieb, I am not trying to change the histfile. commenting out the lines from .bashrc does not change anything in terms of output. $HISTFILESIZE and $HISTSIZE still output 500 because I believe that is the mac default.

Comment: @fd0, I'm not sure what your question means, could you clarify? What's the relationship between .bashrc and a login shell?

Comment: Always quote pathname variable expansions: `HISTFILE="$HOME/.bash_history”`. Without the quotes, your version will be invalid if the path to your home directory contains spaces (or possibly other special characters).

Comment: I was experiencing this same problem because my `.bash_profile` was invoking an `osascript` to quit the terminal process after the last visible window/tab closed. Somehow that script was preventing the history from being stored in my history file when the terminal exited.

Answer (score 32):

Terminal assigns each terminal session a unique identifier and communicates it via the TERM_SESSION_ID environment variable so that programs running in a terminal can save/restore application-specific state when quitting and restarting Terminal with Resume enabled.

A new folder (~/.bash_sessions/) is used to store HISTFILE's and .session files that are unique to sessions.

During shell startup the session file is executed. Old files are periodically deleted.

The default behavior arranges to save and restore the bash command history independently for each restored terminal session. It also merges commands into the global history for new sessions.

You may disable this behavior and share a single history by setting

```
export SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0
```

If HISTTIMEFORMAT is defined, per-session history is disabled by default (read more in /private/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal)

The save/restore mechanism is disabled if the following file exists:

```
~/.bash_sessions_disable
```

Apple already changed some behavior since El Capitan release, so it is better to go read more about this here `less /private/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`

Comment: But don’t just start by disabling the save/restore mechanism. If you’re having issues with the shell command history, try to resolve that issue. The `~/.bash_sessions_disable` file is meant as a last resort in case there’s an issue that can’t be resolved specifically. It disables more than just the per-session command histories, and you can disable just the per-session command history. See the comments in `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` for details.

Comment: @ChrisPage Actually Apple changed some bits of script. Updated answer, thanks.

Comment: @diimdeep Where would I append this line? `export SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0`

Comment: @zerohedge `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310150/15362

Comment: @diimdeep Thank you. This seems to be working right now. Does it have any ramifications?

Answer (score 6):

I noticed something similar after the El Capitan upgrade. Simply adding the file `.bash_sessions_disable` file in your home directory disables the new bash sessions and the `.bash_history` is back in use.

This [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/3g475b/el_capitan_terminal_bash_history_missing/) has more info and further links.

Comment: But don’t just start by disabling the save/restore mechanism. If you’re having issues with the shell command history, try to resolve that issue. The `~/.bash_sessions_disable` file is meant as a last resort in case there’s an issue that can’t be resolved specifically. It disables more than just the per-session command histories, and you can disable just the per-session command history. See the comments in `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` for details.

Comment: Thanks Chris - what else does it disable my history has been working as expected (same as previous osx version and same as linux) for the last couple of months.  Don't know why they changed it?

Comment: @rabs I'd suggest adding `SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0` at the top of `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 5):

You can solve RVM problem by updating to latest RVM version or executing this:

```
  echo 'shell_session_update' > $HOME/.bash_logout
```

See https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3540 for more info.

Comment: Nice fix, without having to modify rvm.

Comment: Are we talking about the Ruby enVironment Manager (RVM) https://rvm.io ?? When and why should that become involved?

Comment: Suggest: `echo 'shell_session_update' >> $HOME/.bash_logout` to preserve the possible file content.

Answer (score 3):

This answer from the [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/3g475b/el_capitan_terminal_bash_history_missing/) saved me:

> It's probably RVM preventing the exit "hook" for bash_sessions to run. If you comment out the following line in your .bash_profile, it should work.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: This indeed helped!

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Mac, I suppose it's default login shell is `bash` and it runs `.profile` instead of `.bashrc`. So, you were editing the wrong file.

Comment: I've edited .profile so it is the same as my .bashrc, and history still doesn't come up.

Comment: @NelsonLiu What happens when you echo `$HISTFILE` in different parts of `profile`? Maybe you source another script that changes the variable? I checked both `Terminal` and `iTerm`, `bash` `3` and `4`  both have their default `$HOME/.bash_history`.

Comment: how would I echo $HISTFILE in different parts of profile?

Comment: @NelsonLiu, isn't it obvious? your aim is to track when does `$HISTFILE` change. Thus, simply make two `echo $HISTFILE` surround your code. What you have to do is to find the piece of code where `$HISTFILE` changes by moving both `echo $HISTFILE` lines closer and closer to each other line-by-line until something reveals. That's all.

Comment: Hi @theoden, sorry for my misunderstanding. Interestingly enough, when I add a `echo $HISTFILE` to the start and end of my `.profile`, no output is produced. when I add an `echo $HISTFILE` to the start and end of my `.bash_profile`, however, the proper $HISTFILE is outputted. (/Users/myuser/.bash_history). What else should I try? Sorry, I'm pretty new to shell.

Comment: @NelsonLiu, if it is really like this, you should 1) make `.bash_profile` same as `.profile` 2) do as I said before.

Comment: so I've done as you instructed and made .bash_profile the same as profile. I decided to `echo $HISTFILE` on every line, just to see if there were any differences. However, it merely printed `/Users/username/.bash_history` a myriad of times. I then ran `echo $HISTFILE` in the shell, and it outputted `/Users/nelsonliu/.bash_sessions/CD275A29-1DF1-4ED8-B8CE-F706B11B812F.historynew`.

Comment: @NelsonLiu, this only means that something else is launched after `bashrc`. Nothing works and noone knows why. Perhaps some suspicious app changes the histfile or something. You can only add a little hack to your `bash_profile` for sure: `sleep 2 && export HISTFILE=~/.bash_history &`.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this problem on High Sierra. Somehow, my own .bash_history had become owned by root and not even having read permissions for other users (when contents of home directory viewed with ls -al)

There was nothing of any consequence in this .bash_history file, so I did a sudo rm .bash_history followed by a touch .bash_history to make a new one.

All seems well now

Comment: For me, it wasn't the file permissions, it was that I hadn't defined any of the HIST control variables. Apparently one or more of them must be defined. I added this to my `~/.bash_profile` file: `export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '`

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;** unset `$HISTFILE` in the zsh / bash RC file

---

I had a similar issue with zsh

- the `$HISTFILE` was set to `~/.history` in `~/.zshrc`
- it was somehow overridden by the OS and ended up in the `~/.zsh_session/XXX` directory (so never saved to the local history file)

But since it was set in my RC file, the shell history did load it from the old `~/.history` and was never up to date

Removing the "manual" setting of the `$HISTFILE` solved the issue in my case